# Why the amd p-state isn't available after enabling and compiling it in the kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, amd-processor, acpi

I'm trying to test the AMD p-state recently [released](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/rui/linux.git/log/?h=amd-pstate-dev-v5) , but after compiling the whole kernel, or applying the respective patch the amd-pstate isn't available for the system.

On the source dir:

```
ls  ~/linux-amd-pstate-dev-v5/drivers/cpufreq/amd*

amd-pstate-trace.c           
amd-pstate-trace.h           
amd-pstate.c
```

after enabling the relevant parts in the config file

```
Processor type and features  --->
  [*] Symmetric multi-processing support
  [*] Support x2apic
  [*] AMD ACPI2Platform devices support
  Processor family (Opteron/Athlon64/Hammer/K8)  --->
    (X) Opteron/Athlon64/Hammer/K8
  [*] Supported processor vendors  --->
    [*]   Support AMD processors (NEW)
  [*] SMT (Hyperthreading) scheduler support
  [*] Multi-core scheduler support
  [*] Machine Check / overheating reporting
  [*]   AMD MCE features
  Performance monitoring  --->
    <*> AMD Processor Power Reporting Mechanism
  [*]   AMD microcode loading support
Power management and ACPI options  --->
  CPU Frequency scaling  --->
      Default CPUFreq governor (ondemand)  --->
      CPU Frequency scaling drivers
         [*]   AMD Processor P-state driver


    <*>   ACPI Processor P-States driver
    [ /*]     Legacy cpb sysfs knob support for AMD CPUs
    < >   AMD Opteron/Athlon64 PowerNow!
    <*>   AMD frequency sensitivity feedback powersave bias
Device Drivers  --->
  Generic Driver Options --->
    (amd-ucode/microcode_amd_fam17h.bin) External firmware blobs to build into the kernel binary
    (/lib/firmware) Firware blobs root directory
  [*] IOMMU Hardware Support  --->
    [*]   AMD IOMMU support
    <*>     AMD IOMMU Version 2 driver
```

And after compiling the kernel, the driver used by cpufreq is

```
driver: acpi-cpufreq
```

I have blacklisted acpi-cpufreq and added to the loadline of the kernel at boot.
And the amd-pstate is inserted using

```
modprobe amd-pstate
```

And it seems to be loading but there is nothing on the terminal.

Then how can compile and enable these module.
I have a ton of Ryzen CPUs and perhaps going to buy more, so it could be interesting to save a bit of power.

Comment: I have basically the same issue, the module seems pretty premature so far, no error output or anything but it also does not load for me on a HP X360 435 G8 with and AMD Ryzen 7 5800U.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using amd_pstate.enable=1 as GRUB parameter?

source: https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/hardware/processors-memory/1297365-amd-p-state-cpu-frequency-control-driver-revised-a-6th-time?p=1297378#post1297378

Comment: No, but I will try again and use a new version of the kernel

Comment: I tried it on my end wtih xanmod's custom kernel on Debian and passing the GRUB parameter 
-------
    ➜  ~ uname -a ----------
    Linux homelab 5.15.27-xanmod1 #0~git20220309.a35c0c7 SMP Wed Mar 9 13:03:03 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux ----------
    ➜  ~ sudo cpupower frequency-info ---------
    analyzing CPU 0:
      driver: amd-pstate
      CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
      CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
      maximum transition latency: 131 us
      hardware limits: 400 MHz - 4.37 GHz

Comment: I forgot to say that our scenarios might be diff: I am using a 5700U processor. I am using the driver as a module. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks  I'm giving another try. The systems using are based on Zen2+, thats supposed to be supported. But I expected by now the driver was included into the main branch. I didn't try as a module, thanks for the idea!!